# channels() returns 1 on RGB image

Tags: java

The `channels()` function return 1 on a RGB image, while it's expected to return 3.

I'm trying to convert a RGB image to grayscale using `Imgproc.cvtColor` from OpenCV library, but I get an error: the convert function return an error indicating the src is not a RGB format.

> if you read a jpg file, a 3 channel image is create by default

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat srcInput = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\LELP_0600.jpg");
        if (srcInput.channels() == 1) {
            System.out.println("One Channel");
        } else if (srcInput.channels() == 3) {
            System.out.println("3 Channels");
        }
}
```

I except the output to be "3 Channels", but the actual output is "One Channel".

Comment: Erm, do you get an error or do you get "One channel" printed? You seem to say that both happen, which is a bit difficult to believe.

Comment: I get an error when i add the line:
Imgproc.cvtColor(srcInput, srcInput, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

Comment: What's the image you're reading? What version of OpenCV are you using? What's your source on "if you read a jpg file, a 3 channel image is create by default"? Also note that `imread` determines the type of an image by the content, not by the file extension, at least in the latest versions of OpenCV.

Comment: Hi,
I'm using 3.4.6 version.

My source in the link:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d5/d98/tutorial_mat_operations.html

I'm reading jpg image. i also tried a BMP file